# Razor page not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

After redirect to Test page.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLoadAsync(IFormFile file)
{
    if(file != null){
        return RedirectToPage("TestPage");
    }
}
```

and invoking Page() nothing happens, at all. No exceptions, errors.

```
public class TestPage : PageModel
{
    private readonly Service _service;

    public TestPage(Service service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is something wrong here. Have a look at your Index page, Index.cshtml. Code-behind for that would be named IndexModel. Question is what your .cshtml file is called. A redirect to Index page would be like this: return RedirectToPage("/Index") or return RedirectToPage("Index"); if you already are at root level.

Comment: According to my test, I successfully entered the TestPage. I hope you will provide us with the code in the front and back of the TestPage for reference, and tell us the hierarchical relationship between the two pages.